# Updating a document with a custom object (struct)

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

We can use a struct to both create and get a document form firestore, but the documentation for updating a document doesn't show that it's possible to use a custom object (struct) here. Instead we have to re-assign each field, but this means we don't know which fields are updating?

What I expect to work

```golang
document.Name = "John Smith" // Could be any field, just an example

ctx := context.Background()
_, err = c.Collection("people").Doc(document.ID).Update(ctx, &document)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

What it says I need to do

```golang
document.Name = "John Smith"

ctx := context.Background()
_, err = c.Collection("people").Doc(document.ID).Update(ctx, []fire.Updates{
    {
        Name:  document.name
    },
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

What if I don't know what has been updated? or what if multiple things in the object have updated? I might have to manually assign each of the structs attributes in the update?

Comment: You can use a custom struct to update a document with the [func (*DocumentRef) Set](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef.Set). Which either creates or replaces the whole document. Does this help?

Comment: @RafaelFT I don't think so as the documentation says `To do a merging Set with struct data, specify the exact fields to overwrite.` this doesn't seem any different from using `Update`. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems to me you do not want a merging update if you want to use the entire struct to update. Are all the fields in your struct set to the value the database should contain after the update, or do you only set some of the fields on the struct? Problem is, that if you don't know which fields have been updated and should be written to the DB, how should firebase? Maybe you can add a concrete example with data to your question of what you want to happen.

Comment: @TehSphinX Yes, the document should reflect the database as often as possible. okay so maybe I should rethink my approach. I'm heading in this direction because this is what you can do with Python and Javascript and firebase figures it out. Maybe instead when a change occurs to the struct an update to firebase needs to happen immediately after, that way I can better provide a context for what changed. E.g. `ChangeName()` -> `UpdateDoc(document, "name")` or an interface with the changes.

Comment: @TehSphinX You're wrong. For instance with Arango DB's Go driver, partial update ('patch') using [incomplete] structure is completely possible. No, developer doesn't know what fields might be sent in the "PATCH" request body; and yes, Arangoddb unlike firestore "knows" which fields of a document to change: https://university.arangodb.com/courses/go-driver-tutorial/lessons/update-a-document/

Comment: @RdB I don't think I said anything against what you are saying.